# get element value by name

Tags: html, web, vbscript

I'm trying to find a specific text value in my HTML page

I'm trying to use the GetElementsByName ( as it does not have any ID )

```
x = msgbox("Wait for page to load",64, "Job ID")
JobId = IE.Document.GetElementsByName("jobId")
x = msgbox((JobId.Value),64, "Job ID")
```

here is the HTML and the value that I want to extract 
Please help THANKS !

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try `x = msgbox((JobId(0).Value),64, "Job ID")`

When you use the GetElementsByName tag, it will be returning back an array. If you only have one item with that `name` tag, you can always use JobID[0] to reference it.

How ever if you are going to have more than one item, you will have to do some sort of loop

```
For Each job in JobID
  msgbox((job.Value),64, "Job ID")
Next
```

You could also do something like this

```
inputs = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
For Each input in inputs
  If input.type = "hidden" && input.name = "JobId" Then
     msgbox((input.Value),64, "Job ID")
  End If
Next
```

Comment: In VBScript, array and collection elements are indicated with parenthesis `JobId(0)` instead of square brackets. Did you mean to use those?

Comment: Hi from some reason I get compilation alert although it looks OK

Comment: I get a NULL error when 'inputs = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")'