# Get element by tag name

Tags: html, vbscript, getelementsbyname

I have a trouble getting an element from HTML page

what I do is I navigate to a site then I want to find an element called "jobId"

```
Dim inputs
Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = 1
IE.Navigate "SOME SITE"
```

then I want to loop through the site ( HTML CODE )

```
Set inputs = IE.Document.GetElementsByName("input")
x = msgbox(inputs)
x = msgbox(inputs.Length)

For each Z in inputs
    x = msgbox("Item =  "+Z,64, "input")
next
```

on the first msgbox I get an error of unspecified error of NULL

the element is in an iFrame ( I don't know if its impacting some how )

when I use ViewSource this is the elements I want to use :

```
<input type="hidden" name="videoUrl" value="https://vid-uss2.sundaysky.com:443/v1/w38/flvstreamer?jobId=5850f72f-46e1-49e1-953b-2a9acdf6dd01&authToken=d88fc69cea0c48769c3cd42e8481cd47&videoId=default"></input>
<input type="hidden" name="videoSessionId" value=""></input>
<input type="hidden" name="displaySurvey" value="true"></input>
<input type="hidden" name="isFlashPlayer" value="true"></input>
<input type="hidden" name="posterLocation" value="http://d21o24qxwf7uku.cloudfront.net/customers/att/attlogoinvitation.png"></input>
<input type="hidden" name="jobId" value="5850f72f-46e1-49e1-953b-2a9acdf6dd01"></input>
<input type="hidden" name="sundayskyBaseUri" value="https://att.web.sundaysky.com/"></input>
<input type="hidden" name="oldBucketMode" value="false"></input>
```

this is followed by my previous post [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22156192/get-element-value-by-name)

following your instructions I got to this point :

```
Dim jobId
Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = 1
IE.Navigate "https://att.web.sundaysky.com/viewbill?bk=dNEdk01ykHC72rQil7D_iTzfjn7Qj4FN6fvJ_YE-ndY"
x = msgbox("Wait for page to load",64, "Job ID")
set jobId = IE.document.getElementsByName("jobId")
x = msgbox(jobId,64, "Job ID")
```

this is what I get ( and that's my best yet )
[image]

Please help
Thanks !!

Comment: I tried using a loop to find especially the Job ID but eventually I tried just to show everything that I get from the SET inputs I thought using xpath but I don't know how to extract it and I'm not sure if it is constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using [`getElementsByName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536438%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) when you actually mean to use [`getElementsByTagName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536439%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The former returns elements based on the value of their *attribute* `name`:

```
<input name="videoUrl" ...>
```

whereas the latter returns elements based on the name of the *tag*:

```
<input name="videoUrl" ...>
```

**Edit:** Two other things I noticed:

- You don't seem to wait for IE to finish loading the page (which might explain why you're getting `Null` results). The `Navigate` method returns immediately, so you have to wait for the page to finish loading:

  ```
  Do
    WScript.Sleep 100
  Loop Until IE.ReadyState = 4
  ```
- `inputs` contains a `DispHTMLElementCollection`, not a string, so trying to display it with a `MsgBox` will give you a type error. Same goes for the members of the collection. If you want to display the tags in string form use the objects' `outerHtml` property:

  ```
  For Each Z In inputs
    MsgBox "Item =  " & Z.outerHtml, 64, "input"
  Next
  ```

**Edit2:** To get just the value of the attribute `value` of elements whose `name` attribute has the value `jobId` you could use this:

```
For Each jobId In IE.document.getElementsByName("jobId")
  WScript.Echo jobId.value
Next
```

**Edit3:** The page you're trying to process contains an `iframe` (sorry, I failed to notice that earlier). This is what prevents your code from working. Element getter methods like `getElementsByName` or `getElementsByTagName` don't work across frame boundaries, so you need to run those methods on the *content* of the `iframe`. This should work:

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True

ie.Navigate "http://..."

Do
  WScript.Sleep 100
Loop Until ie.ReadyState = 4

'get the content of the iframe
Set iframe = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).contentWindow

'get the jobId input element inside the iframe
For Each jobId In iframe.document.getElementsByName("jobId")
  MsgBox jobId.value, 64, "Job ID"
Next
```

Comment: just tried Set inputs = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input") still I get null ...

Comment: @Light_User: `getElementsByTagName` should return an `DispHTMLElementCollection`, regardless of whether tags with the given name were found or not. You can't simply print the collection or its elements, though, since they're not strings (or a datatype that could be converted to string). If you want the whole tag printed, use the object's `outerHtml` property.

Comment: I just want the Job Id printed ... my problem is that it fails on the set inputs , not on the msgbox ...

Comment: OK first regarding loading ( i used it manually, on hold by msgbox , after it loaded I clicked and it proceeded the script) Thanks ! second I still get the same error of error '80004005' Unspecified error and only on the line where get elements appear , by the way used the loop untill IE ready -> and it was never ready .... but it's wrong as when I do view source it appears there ...

Comment: @Light_User: Please update your question with the (full) code you're using now and the exact error message.

Comment: I read your comment and the last update is the full code ( it's really short ) and there is no error ( I still wait manually ) it's not failing on the Set jobId , but I can't show it correctly and as posted it shows "[object HTMLCollection]"

Comment: just tried it , works GREAT !! I suspected that this iFrame might be a problem , indeed it was , THANK YOU !!!